# execute code on scroll/only visible associated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function applies to a lot of html elements on the page and some of them are visible only when you scroll down the page.  I want the code to execute for the elements that are only dispalyed on the page so you get to see the function run for the elements associated with the function as you scroll.... similar to a scroll reveal but in this case its sort of like a scroll execute this code.  Any help is gratefully recieved.

```
function circle_progess() {

    var divElement = $('div'); //log all div elements

    if (retina()) {

        $(".whiteCircle").knob({
            'min':0,
            'max':100,
            'readOnly': true,
            'width': 240,
            'height': 240,
            'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
            'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
            'dynamicDraw': true,
            'thickness': 0.2,
            'tickColorizeValues': true
        });

        $(".circleStat").css('zoom',0.5);
        $(".whiteCircle").css('zoom',0.999);


    } else {

        $(".whiteCircle").knob({
            'min':0,
            'max':100,
            'readOnly': true,
            'width': 120,
            'height': 120,
            'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
            'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
            'dynamicDraw': true,
            'thickness': 0.2,
            'tickColorizeValues': true
        });

    }



        $(".circleStatsItemBox").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).find(".count > .number").html();
  var unit = $(this).find(".value > .unit").html();
  var percent = $(this).find("input").val() / 100;

  countSpeed = 2300 * percent;
  endValue = value;

  $(this).find(".count > .unit").html(unit);
  $(this).find(".count > .number").countTo({
    from: 0,
    to: endValue,
    speed: countSpeed,
    refreshInterval: 50
  });

  //$(this).find(".count").html(value*percent + unit);
});

}
```

i want something like this at the top of the code....

```
if .circleStatsItemBox, .whitecircle are not visible on page then dont run the code.
```

this is the html in snippet ... there are lots of these all over the web page ...

```
<div class="span2" ontablet="span4" ondesktop="span2">
<div class="circleStatsItemBox yellow">
<div class="header">Levels of Interest</div>
<span class="percent">% Increase</span>
<div class="circleStat"> <input value="11" class="whiteCircle" type="text"> </div>
<div class="footer"><span class="count"> <span class="number">80</span> <span class="unit">Before</span>
</span> <span class="sep"> / </span> <span class="value"> <span class="number">90</span><span class="unit"> During</span></span> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span2" ontablet="span4" ondesktop="span2">
<div class="circleStatsItemBox green">
<div class="header">Levels of Response</div>
<span class="percent">% Increase</span>
<div class="circleStat"> <input value="0" class="whiteCircle" type="text"> </div>
<div class="footer"> <span class="count"> <span class="number">90</span> <span class="unit">Before</span>
</span> <span class="sep"> / </span> <span class="value"> <span class="number">90</span><span class="unit"> During</span></span> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span2" ontablet="span4" ondesktop="span2">
<div class="circleStatsItemBox red">
<div class="header">Levels of Initiation</div>
<span class="percent">% Increase</span>
<div class="circleStat"> <input value="4" class="whiteCircle" type="text"> </div>
<div class="footer"><span class="count"> <span class="number">60</span> <span class="unit">Before</span>
</span> <span class="sep"> / </span> <span class="value"> <span class="number">63</span><span class="unit"> During</span></span> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add fiddle?

Comment: You can use this plugin : https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport  to check if element is in view port or not. In your case you can check same thing on scroll event of jquery and execute code or call your desired function.
Also Make sure that you call your function once only while scrolling.

Comment: Hi yeah no problem on the fiddle sorry i didn't put one in Will add fiddle later when i get back to house, am currently on phone grrrr

Comment: thanks for the advice on the plugin I will check it out when i get home on my computer.  It is worth me mentioning that the code is executed on a rcurring class element of the same name... i hope this doesnt affect things too much

Comment: I have posted an example of the html that relates to the function... there are lots of these html bits all over the page and just took 3 of them for the purpose of this example

Comment: i am not sure how you would use the zeusdeux plugin with this particular function  ? can you assist ?